# How to list all images in a directory and include them with php

Tags: php

I try to list all images that have been uploaded to the website and embed them with a foreach loop, all I see is just a "not working" thumbnail, like a placeholder for the images, while the image url is already correct.
the code:

```
$scan = scandir('images');
foreach ($scan as $image){
    echo "<img src=\"$image\"> ";
}
```

I am working with windows xampp environment, just for testing purposes, but i can't test it anywhere else yet, so i can't say if it's a windows thing or not :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Almost. Use [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob). Make sure the path  is relative to httpdocs.

Comment: Check the console and see where it goes wrong.
You can see which image path you are trying to load.
Also, as Markus said, use glob.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows Check the console? This is PHP. What console are you talking about?

Comment: @Timberman You can see where images failed to load in the network section in your web browser, this can show him if the links he's trying to include are broken.

Answer (score 2):

If the images were in a folder called `images` then add that to the src attribute

```
$scan = scandir('images');
foreach ($scan as $image){
    // remember to remove the `.` and `..` folders
    if ( $image != '.' && $image != '..'){
        echo '<img src="images/$image">';
    }
}
```